# Symfony2 upload file without form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, file-upload

Using symfony2, I would like to upload some files only from their path on my PC.

I read an excel file containing some path to pictures (like /home/thibault/pictures/*.jpg) and I want to upload them on my server. So, I do not want a form.

All the documentation I have read deal with upload from a form, is this possible to do that without ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Impossible due to potential security exploits. What if someone decided to "pull" `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` for example? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible.  For what you are looking for you need to deploy some locally running agent.  Any browser will not permit you to pull files form folders on the user's computer.  The user has to be the one to say what files they want to upload if it is to be done inside a browser.

Comment: I have an excel file with 1500 user to upload. In this file there is a field containing the path to this picture. Do you say that I'm strained to upload my pictures one by one with a form ? There is no other way to automate this task ?

Comment: There are Flash and Java Applet based batch up loaders but the user still has to select the images.